# When and how does one start an informative "wiki" type "article" on SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

Given that StackOverflow's underlying site engine is designed to provide a blend of forum, wiki and blog, I am curious about the validity of starting threads to be informational, rather than question-oriented. There are numerous tidbits of useful information that I have encountered in my work with .NET, C#, CSS, JavaScript, etc. etc.

When I have a question, a Bing search usually brings up several SO articles in the first page. It has become an invaluable resource for common questions. However, there is still a lot of useful information that can currently only be gleaned by digging through pages and pages of MSDN articles or W3C, WS-* standards, or Wikipedia, followed by a few hours of tinkering with plenty of trial and error. I think it would be extremely handy to have more consolidated resource off useful information or powerful, time-saving tips & tricks...for example, how to implement x.509 security that is compatible with WCF and Java (a topic that is SORELY lacking in any useful, exemplified, and clearly understandable documentation.)

So, what are the rules about creating an informative SO post, with request for comments and refinements? Is such a thing "kosher"...or is SO (and its sister sites) really more of a forum than a Wiki/Blog?

Answer (score 4):

Well, in general this is covered in the /faq --

> It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

So, basically, just make sure whatever information you wish to share fits the Q&A format and that you have a specific-ish question with a specific-ish answer.

Comment: So, it is not ok to have a non-question "wiki" type article on SO?

Comment: @jrista exactly.